# How to increase the screen log size in GNU Screen?

Tags: logging, save, gnu-screen

Is there a way to increase the screen log size? I cannot save all my history.

```
$ screen -S creed1
$ command1
output command 1... (50 lines)
$ command2
output command 2... (200 lines)
$ command3
output command 3... (60 lines)
$ command4
output command 4... (75 lines)
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> (saving to `hardcopy.0`)

`vim hardcopy.0` shows only the last 100 lines approx.

I wanna know this for compliance purposes with a customer.

Answer (score 1):

You want to do Ctrl+A + H at the beginning to start logging, not when you are done.

I found that out and other screen commands here:
http://www.computerhope.com/unix/screen.htm